# Neo4j Importing local CSV File

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to import a local csv file but I have got InvalidSyntax Error.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM file:C:/csv/user.csv
```

Invalid input '/' (line 1, column 35 (offset: 34))
    "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM file:C:/csv/user.csv"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to put the filename in quotes, and add a few more slashes:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/csv/user.csv"
```

Full documentation [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html).

Comment: Comment `dbms.directories.import=import` in your database's settings.

Answer (score 9):

The command below will return the first 5 lines of your CSV file:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///<PATH_TO_YOUR_CSV_FILE>" AS line WITH line RETURN line LIMIT 5;
```

But you'll have to follow some steps to align with Neo4J security restrictions.

1) Find the conf folder in the neo4j server folder.
Open the neo4j.conf with a text editor.

2) Uncomment the line containing:

```
#dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
```

To uncomment it, just remove #. It should be like this:

```
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
```

3) Comment this line below:

```
dbms.directories.import=import
```

To comment it, add #. It should be like this:

```
#dbms.directories.import=import
```

Further on importing from CSV in neo4j documentation here: https://neo4j.com/blog/importing-data-neo4j-via-csv/

Comment: I found I needed to do this in Neo4J Desktop: Database > Manage > Settings and  format <PATH_TO_YOUR_CSV_FILE>  like: C:/path/to/file.csv - IE with forward slashes

Answer (score 3):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/path/location/filename.csv" AS row
```

Found that these query asks Neo4j to look in a specific location 
C:\Users\*******\.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-2b9d81ff-1976-427e-ba98-4f3191c3ef62\installation-3.4.9\import

placing your csv here and using the query

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///testData2.csv" AS line

solved the issue for me

or you can change the settings by making changes here

```
dbms.directories.import=import
```

NB: I am using windows 10 , neo4j-desktop-offline-1.1.12

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem (in Windows 10) and I realized that I was just trying to load the CSV file without saying to it to return something. 
For me it worked pretty well like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:all_data.csv" AS line

RETURN line
```

Note: Do **not** forget to place the CSV file that you want to import on the neo4j import file!