# Not able to load csv file from local machine in Windows

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to load .csv file in Neo4j and getting below mentioned error:

Syntax : LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/Username/Downloads/products.csv"

Error : 
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Neo4j/import/Users/Username/Downloads/products.csv

While I am able to load this file when it is placed in import directory.
Please suggest how I can load this from local hard disk.
While search, I found this options to debug this error-

"You can add the following setting in conf/neo4j.conf in order to bypass this :

dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true"

--I couldn't find any config file/folder in this path.

Comment: What is the actual path of the file disk?

Comment: File Path : "C:\Users\username\Downloads\products.csv"

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299077/neo4j-importing-local-csv-file), you need to specify an absolute path to a file when using `LOAD CSV` with a local file.  However, it appears that you specified a *relative* path, and Neo4j seems to be interpreting it as belonging to the folder from which you (possibly) executed the command.  In other words, you entered the relative path `/Users/Username...`, and Neo4j put this into its own folder.

From the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/):

> Make sure to use the right URLs esp. file URLs.+ On OSX and Unix use file:///path/to/data.csv, **on Windows, please use file:c:/path/to/data.csv**

Therefore, try the following:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:C:/Users/Username/Downloads/products.csv"
```

Comment: I have already tried with full absolute path as mentioned below but still getting same error :        "Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Neo4j/import/Users/Username/Downloads/products.csv"                       Syntax used : "file:///C:/Users/Username/Downloads/products.csv"

Comment: @Apy I updated my answer after checking th3 Neo4j documentation.  It looks like we had the file URL in the UNIX format instead of Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately that I tried earlier and it didn't work. Error : "URI is not hierarchical" ..I am giving correct file path as "file:C:/Users/Username/Downloads/products.csv"